# What are the major specs to compare different triacs?

Tags: triac

I need to replace a broken BT134-600E triac. I found out it's 600V 4A sensitive gate triac. Are these two figures the only ratings to consider when searching out equivalent triacs suitable for replacement in the original PCB the triac was soldered to?

I've gathered a collection of candidate triacs below, what parameters need to be evaluated in order to verify which triacs if any from this list can be used to replace the original one and why?

- MAC97A6
- MAC97A8
- BTA16-600B
- BT137-600
- BT138-600
- BTA208X-800E

All the triacs datasheets can be easily found on google.
The broken (exploded) triac is from a cheap soldering iron which has a really simple circuit.

Thanks :)

[image: soldering iron PCB top view] [image: soldering iron PCB bottom view]

*Front and rear of soldering iron PCB. Click or double-click for hi-resolution.*

Comment: Please edit your question to state the requirements of the application (current, voltage, type of load, trigger voltage/current, etc.) and the basic specification of the original triac. Which of the possible substitutions seems most appropriate to you and what are you unsure about?

Comment: done. I've no idea which one is the most appropriate cause i don't know how triacs work, that's why i'm asking

Comment: Read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC and ask a better question

Comment: Will any 600V 4A (or more) sensitive gate triac be ok? How can i ask a better question?

Comment: Try to understand all the specs and ask about the ones you do not understand.

Comment: Note that the TRIAC "exploding" (at least, that's what it looks like) might not be the problem but the **result** of another problem. These TRIACs don't just blow themselves up. My point: you can spend all your effort on replacing the TRIAC but if you don't solve the root cause, that new TRIAC might blow up as well. Also: as it is a "cheap soldering iron" why not simply buy a new one or take the chance to upgrade to a better one.

Comment: When stumbling upon a new component try out a Compare Products feature such as at https://www.mouser.com/Compare/. The various rows that get rendered and enumerated in the table do well to highlight the key specifications for the parts. If you happen to find an exact match then you've accomplished finding a match and should just order that part. But for close variations you may need to make a judgement call if its close enough. The tricky bit is knowing the characteristics of the device you'll be installing it on and what demands it places on the component. That takes more work to tease out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A triac is just a three terminal semiconductor device. Electrically, you only really need to consider two states - off and on.

In the off state it must withstand a certain voltage across its terminals without conducting. That's the 600V rating.

In the on state it must withstand a certain current through it. That's the 4A rating.

To go from the off state to the on state it must be triggered by a gate current. That's the "gate trigger current" you see in all the datasheets.

So your target device, the BT134-600E, has ratings 600V/25A/4A/10mA for off voltage, on current peak, on current RMS and trigger current respectively. The first option in your list, the MAC97A6, has corresponding ratings 400/8/0.6/5. It has lower off state withstand and lower on state withstand. It requires less trigger current, but should be dismissed due to its lower withstand ratings.

Continue that assessment for all your other options looking for something with sufficient withstand ratings, and a low enough trigger current. Once you have a shortlist you can start to look closer at other ratings that might be relevant, such as thermal impedance, mechanical fit, etc.